# How to Capture Run Time in an Oracle Stored Procedure

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures

I'm wanting to log the run time of certain SELECT stored procedures in Oracle. I've broken this down into the following steps.

- STEP 1 - Get StartTime
- STEP 2 - Insert into the LOG Table that the proc is running
- STEP 3 - Get Inserted RowId
- STEP 4 - Run the SELECT statement within the Proc
- STEP 5 - Get End Time
- STEP 5 - Update the row (in LOG Table) that was inserted, with the "Total Run Time".

IMPORTANT NOTE:  The SELECT statement takes several minutes to run.

What happens is this:

1. The procedure runs
2. A row gets inserted into the LOG table
3. The LOG table immediately gets updated with the total run time.
4. The SELECT statement continues to take 5 minutes to run
5. After the SELECT statement completes, the result data finally returns.

The LOG table should NOT be updated until the entire procedure completes.

Basically what's happening is that the procedure immediately inserts, then updates the LOG table "BEFORE" the SELECT statement finishes.

I've tried wrapping and nesting additional BEGIN and END statements. The stored procedure still runs the "UPDATE" statement at the end of the procedure BEFORE the SELECT statement returns.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE EDITIONABLE PROCEDURE SP_CUSTOMERDATA_GET ( 
   PARAM_USERID       IN    VARCHAR2,
   PARAM_FIRSTNAME    IN    VARCHAR2,   
   PARAM_LASTNAME    IN     VARCHAR2      
   OUTPUT              OUT types.cursor_type)
AS
BEGIN

DECLARE
l_Id Number;
l_StartTime TIMESTAMP;
l_EndTime TIMESTAMP;
l_TotalTime Number;

BEGIN

    l_StartTime:= systimestamp;

    INSERT INTO PROC_LOG (SPNAME, PARM1, PARM2, PARM3)
    VALUES ('SP_CUSTOMERDATA_GET',I_USERNAME, PARAM_USERID, PARAM_FIRSTNAME, PARAM_LASTNAME)
    RETURNING ID INTO l_Id;
    COMMIT;

    OPEN OUTPUT FOR 

    SELECT * 
     FROM CUSTOMER 
    WHERE USERID=PARAM_USERID
      AND FIRSTNAME=PARAM_FIRSTNAME 
      AND LASTNAME=PARAM_LASTNAME; 

  l_EndTime:= systimestamp;      
  l_TotalTime:=  extract(second from (l_EndTime-l_StartTime));

  --ISSUE: This statement runs before the SELECT statement above completes
  UPDATE PROC_LOG
  SET RUNTIME_SECONDS=l_TotalTime
  WHERE ID=l_Id;  
  COMMIT;        


END;

END SP_CUSTOMERDATA_GET;
```

Is there a property I can set in the PROC, to force the procedure to not run the next command until the prior command finishes. It doesn't make sense that the procedure doesn't run in order?

Comment: What you're measuring above is the time to open the cursor, not the time to fetch the data. "Opening" a cursor generally is pretty fast - I believe it's mostly setting up data structures with minimal I/O. it's the first row fetch where real time is spent.  If you want to measure the data fetch time you'll have to use a loop to fetch the data, and you might want to have special-case checks to figure out which fetch takes the longest, shortest, tallest, smells-the-best, most-likely-to-succeed, etc. I suggest writing a package to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I re-read the question and Justin's comments, and based on his proposal came up with a code solution for it.
First a general setup of database structures:

```
FSITJA@db01>create table customer (userid,
  2                         firstname,
  3                         lastname) as
  4  select level, 'John', 'Doe'
  5    from dual
  6  connect by level <= 1000000;

Table created.

FSITJA@db01>create table PROC_LOG (id number generated as identity,
  2                         SPNAME varchar2(30),
  3                         PARM1 varchar2(100),
  4                         PARM2 varchar2(100),
  5                         PARM3 varchar2(100),
  6                         RUNTIME_SECONDS number);

Table created.

FSITJA@db01>create or replace type tp_customer_row as object (userid  number,
  2                                                    firstname varchar2(100),
  3                                                    lastname  varchar2(100));
  4  /

Type created.

FSITJA@db01>create or replace type tp_customer as table of tp_customer_row;
  2  /

Type created.

FSITJA@db01>create or replace package types as
  2    type cursor_type is ref cursor return customer%rowtype;
  3  end;
  4  /

Package created.
```

Then we will need a stored procedure with the autonomous transaction to log the time, and the table function that allows us to query data from a collection. We can pass a cursor into the function in a Select to test that it works:

```
FSITJA@db01>create or replace procedure sp_log_customerdata_get(proc_log_id in proc_log.id%type, starttime in timestamp) as
  2    pragma autonomous_transaction;
  3  begin
  4    UPDATE PROC_LOG
  5       SET RUNTIME_SECONDS=extract(second from (systimestamp-starttime))
  6     WHERE ID=proc_log_id;
  7    COMMIT;
  8  end;
  9  /

Procedure created.
FSITJA@db01>create or replace function fn_customerdata_get(cust_cursor types.cursor_type,
  2                                                 proc_log_id in proc_log.id%type,
  3                                                 starttime   in timestamp) return tp_customer
  4  pipelined as
  5    in_cust_rec  customer%rowtype;
  6    out_cust_rec tp_customer_row := tp_customer_row(null, null, null);
  7  begin
  8    loop
  9      fetch cust_cursor into in_cust_rec;
 10      exit when cust_cursor%notfound;
 11      out_cust_rec.userid    := in_cust_rec.userid;
 12      out_cust_rec.firstname := in_cust_rec.firstname;
 13      out_cust_rec.lastname  := in_cust_rec.lastname;
 14      pipe row(out_cust_rec);
 15    end loop;
 16    close cust_cursor;
 17    sp_log_customerdata_get(proc_log_id, starttime);
 18    return;
 19  end;
 20  /

Function created.

FSITJA@db01>select *
  2    from table(fn_customerdata_get(cursor(select userid,
  3                                                 firstname,
  4                                                 lastname
  5                                            from customer
  6                                           where rownum < 5),
  7                                   null,
  8                                   systimestamp));

    USERID FIRSTNAME       LASTNAME
---------- --------------- ---------------
         1 John            Doe
         2 John            Doe
         3 John            Doe
         4 John            Doe
```

Now the original procedure, which will call the function passing a ref cursor, and then forward this cursor out in its parameter for the client application:

```
FSITJA@db01>CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE SP_CUSTOMERDATA_GET (
  2     PARAM_USERID       IN    VARCHAR2,
  3     PARAM_FIRSTNAME    IN    VARCHAR2,
  4     PARAM_LASTNAME     IN    VARCHAR2,
  5     OUTPUT             OUT   types.cursor_type) AS
  6    l_Id Number;
  7    l_StartTime TIMESTAMP;
  8    l_EndTime TIMESTAMP;
  9    l_TotalTime Number;
 10    l_CustResult tp_customer;
 11  BEGIN
 12    l_StartTime:= systimestamp;
 13    INSERT INTO PROC_LOG (SPNAME, PARM1, PARM2, PARM3)
 14    VALUES ('SP_CUSTOMERDATA_GET', PARAM_USERID, PARAM_FIRSTNAME, PARAM_LASTNAME)
 15    RETURNING ID INTO l_Id;
 16    COMMIT;
 17    open output for
 18    select *
 19      from table(fn_customerdata_get(cursor(SELECT userid,
 20                                                   firstname,
 21                                                   lastname
 22                                              FROM CUSTOMER
 23                                             WHERE USERID=PARAM_USERID
 24                                               AND FIRSTNAME=PARAM_FIRSTNAME
 25                                               AND LASTNAME=PARAM_LASTNAME),
 26                                             l_Id,
 27                                             l_StartTime
 28                                    )
 29                );
 30  END SP_CUSTOMERDATA_GET;
 31  /

Procedure created.
```

And finally a piece of code to test that only after the client application fetches data from the table function there will be a log entry for time elapsed:

```
FSITJA@db01>declare
  2    v_output types.cursor_type;
  3    v_runtime_seconds number;
  4    type tp_cust_table is table of customer%rowtype;
  5    v_cust_table tp_cust_table;
  6  begin
  7    SP_CUSTOMERDATA_GET (1, 'John', 'Doe', v_output);
  8    select runtime_seconds
  9      into v_runtime_seconds
 10      from proc_log
 11     where id = 1;
 12    dbms_output.put_line('Runtime before client fetches: ' || v_runtime_seconds);
 13    fetch v_output
 14      bulk collect into v_cust_table;
 15    select runtime_seconds
 16      into v_runtime_seconds
 17      from proc_log
 18     where id = 1;
 19    dbms_output.put_line('Runtime AFTER client fetches: ' || v_runtime_seconds);
 20  end;
 21  /
Runtime before client fetches:
Runtime AFTER client fetches: .118791

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

Comment: Francisco - Thanks, but doing a "SELECT INTO" doesn't return data.  I'm needing an output of several hundred or several thousand records.

Comment: Hi Robbie, upon understanding what the real requirement was I wrote a different solution. Thanks to Justin as well.

Comment: Amazing detailed solution Francisco!  That's a different way of doing it, but it works.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your procedure doesn't actually run the `SELECT` statement.  Your procedure just opens the cursor which parses the statement and gets the statement handle.  It doesn't cause the database to actually execute the statement.  That happens when the caller goes to fetch data from the cursor that is returned.  When the procedure finishes, it has no idea whether the caller is ever going to fetch data from the cursor, whether it is going to just fetch the first 10 rows, or whether it is going to eventually fetch every row.  If your goal is to measure how long it takes to fetch the data from the cursor, you'd want to add logging to the caller not to this procedure.

Of course, you could also just run the `SELECT` statement separately.  If the actual query is anything close to what you posted, I'd strongly wager that you're missing an index on `customer`.  I'd guess that `userID` is unique so if there was an index on `userID`, that query should run in a few milliseconds.

Comment: Justin Cave - So, based on what you are saying, the Select statement runs by the caller and that the caller would have to invoke some type of logging.  It's not possible in this scenario, as the caller is a crystal report interface.  If you can think of a way to do this within the proc itself, let me know.  Also, to answer your question, the select statement provided is just a quick mock to simplify this post.  

Thank you.

Comment: @Robbieone - If you don't mind completely restructuring everything, you could potentially build a pipelined table function, fetch all the data into a local collection, log how long that took (which would require a logging proc that uses an autonomous transaction), and then pipe the data to the client.  That's not the most efficient way to return data but if we're only talking about several thousand rows that's probably not a terrible additional overhead.